# Laravel not loading assets on IIS 8 Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, iis, laravel-5

My server is on IIS 8 running php 7.0 . Everything is working fine. Just issue is with assets they're not being loaded. I'm quite beginner in Laravel
my blade file 
My blade file that i'm trying to load in controller and get errors shown below. 
Stackoverflow is not allowing me to paste more code here. So here is link 
https://pastebin.com/u6Kysf2x

My web.config file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
 <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <clear />
            <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI1" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
             </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm also beginner with iis i just used wordpress and many other cms here and also used code iginitor here .

What my site is throwing error 
[image]

Comment: try like `<img src="{{asset('/img/mailbox_imgs/5.jpg')}}"` instead `<img src="{{asset('assets/img/mailbox_imgs/5.jpg')}}"`

Comment: In my code i've done that too nothing beneficial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the mistake i was doing is not running

```
npm install
```

and i was not using laravel mix to compile assets. You can refer to this doc to compile your js and css assets in laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix